# Cannot find child elements of custom view after inflated

Tags: android

I am trying to inflate a custom view on activity load and then do something with the child elements of that view. Below I try to inflate the view and then get a reference to a TextView within the layout XML to update the text value. However in the below code, after the last line, actionBarTitle is null - when I would expect it to be a reference to a TextView. What am I doing wrong?

Activity onCreate() method

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_userseed);

LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        actionBarView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.fragment_actionbar_viewseed, null);
        TextView actionBarTitle = (TextView) actionBarView.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
}
```

And the layout XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager     
        android:id="@+id/actionbar_pager"     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"     
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
            android:id="@+id/actionbar_pagerstrip"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

TextView actionBarTitle = (TextView) actionBarView.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);